# Cannot exit Google Device Manager Installer

Tags: android-device-manager

For reasons unexplained, I loaded Google Device Manager.  Near the end of the installation, when I got to the screen where it lists all of the things that the IT team can do, and that the camera was going to be disabled, I tapped Cancel.

That took me back one screen.  I tapped the X in the upper right and exited the installer.  However, now I have a continual triangle notification in the upper left of the screen,  When I view it, it says "Account Action Required" and my e-mail address.  When I tap it, it takes me right back to the screen after had tapped Cancel (above).

If I uninstall from Google Play, it comes back after I reboot.

How do I kill this installer for good?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you installed **Google Apps Device Policy**. Then you need to follow these steps from [the official Google support site](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/2364439?hl=en) to uninstall and unregister yourself.

> 1. Open Google Apps Device Policy on your Android device.
> 2. On the Status screen, touch Unregister for each account you have registered with the device.
> 3. Depending on your device, go to one of the following:
>
>    - Settings > Applications > Manage Applications
>    - Settings > Apps.
> 4. Select Google Apps Device Policy.
> 5. Touch Uninstall or Disable and then OK to remove it.
>
> Alternatively, you can deactivate the Google Apps Device Policy app and then uninstall or disable it:
>
> 1. On your Android device, go to Settings > Security.
> 2. Touch one of the following:
>
>    - Select device administrators
>    - Device administrators
> 3. Uncheck Google Apps Device Policy.
> 4. Touch Deactivate.
> 5. Touch OK.
> 6. Depending on your device, go to one of the following:
>
>    - Settings > Applications > Manage Applications
>    - Settings > Apps.
> 7. Touch Google Apps Device Policy.
> 8. Touch Uninstall or Disable and then OK to remove it.

Comment: Thanks. This occurred *before* I completed the installation, so there was no GADP to disable or uninstall.  What *did* work was to continue the installation despite the dire warnings that the IT dept was going to take over my personal phone.  What happened next may not be helpful to others, but in my case (US Govt e-mail), we have G-Suite, but I received a message "No G-Suite account" and then the whole thing uninstalled itself with all kinds of warnings that my account was being removed, etc., etc.  After it was complete, I found that I could still access my .gov email via Chrome as before.